# Clojure "repeatedly" makes "future" run sequentially

Tags: clojure

While this snippet

```
(dorun 
  (map deref 
    (map #(future 
            (println % (Thread/currentThread))) 
         (range 10))))
```

prints 10 intermixed lines showing different threads:

```
0 #object[java.lang.Thread 0x5f1b4a83 Thread[clojure-agent-send-off-pool-26,5,main]]                                                                                                                           
2 #object[java.lang.Thread 1 0x79dfba1f #object[Thread[clojure-agent-send-off-pool-28,5,main]java.lang.Thread]                                                                                                 
3 4 #object[java.lang.Thread #object[java.lang.Thread 0x7ef7224f Thread[clojure-agent-send-off-pool-27,5,main]0x5f1b4a83 ]Thread[clojure-agent-send-off-pool-26,5,main]]                                       
5                                                                                                                                                                                                              
67  #object[java.lang.Thread #object[0x79dfba1f java.lang.Thread Thread[clojure-agent-send-off-pool-28,5,main]]0x77526645                                                                                      
 8 #object[java.lang.Thread #object[java.lang.ThreadThread[clojure-agent-send-off-pool-29,5,main] ]9 #object[java.lang.Thread 0xc143aa5 0x7ef7224f                                                             Thread[clojure-agent-send-off-pool-31,5,main]]Thread[clojure-agent-send-off-pool-27,5,main]]                                                                                                                       

0x1ce8675f 0x379ae862 Thread[clojure-agent-send-off-pool-30,5,main]Thread[clojure-agent-send-off-pool-32,5,main]]]
```

as I would expect, the following snippet:

```
(dorun
  (map deref 
    (map #(future 
            (println % (Thread/currentThread))) 
         (repeatedly 10 #(identity 42)))))
```

produces 10 neatly aligned strings with the same thread:

```
42 #object[java.lang.Thread 0x1e1b7ffb Thread[clojure-agent-send-off-pool-39,5,main]]                                                                                                                              
42 #object[java.lang.Thread 0x1e1b7ffb Thread[clojure-agent-send-off-pool-39,5,main]]                                                                                                                              
42 #object[java.lang.Thread 0x1e1b7ffb Thread[clojure-agent-send-off-pool-39,5,main]]                                                                                                                              
42 #object[java.lang.Thread 0x1e1b7ffb Thread[clojure-agent-send-off-pool-39,5,main]]                                                                                                                              
42 #object[java.lang.Thread 0x1e1b7ffb Thread[clojure-agent-send-off-pool-39,5,main]]                                                                                                                              
42 #object[java.lang.Thread 0x1e1b7ffb Thread[clojure-agent-send-off-pool-39,5,main]]                                                                                                                              
42 #object[java.lang.Thread 0x1e1b7ffb Thread[clojure-agent-send-off-pool-39,5,main]]                                                                                                                              
42 #object[java.lang.Thread 0x1e1b7ffb Thread[clojure-agent-send-off-pool-39,5,main]]                                                                                                                              
42 #object[java.lang.Thread 0x1e1b7ffb Thread[clojure-agent-send-off-pool-39,5,main]]                                                                                                                              
42 #object[java.lang.Thread 0x1e1b7ffb Thread[clojure-agent-send-off-pool-39,5,main]]
```

which clearly indicates that the futures are not run in parallel, but each in the same thread.

This happens only with `repeatedly`, even if I realize the sequence with `doall` first, but vectors, `range`s or other sequences all result in parallel execution.

Why is future dispatching to the same thread when `repeatedly` is used?

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This works:

```
(dorun (map deref (doall (map #(future (println % (Thread/currentThread))) (repeatedly 10 #(identity 42))))))
```

The problem is that `range` produces a **chunked** sequence while `repeatedly` produces an **unchunked** sequence. Map is lazy, so in the `repeatedly` case you're creating a future, then derefing it, then creating the next future, then dereffing it. In the `range` case the sequence is chunked so you're creating all futures and then `deref`ing all of them.

Here's another fun way to observe the difference between the behaviour of chunked and unchunked sequences.

```
=> (first (map prn (range 10)))
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
nil
=> (first (map prn (repeatedly 10 #(identity 13))))
13
nil
```

The size of the chunks is usually 32 (but I think that's not guaranteed anywhere), as can be seen if you run `(first (map prn (range 1000)))`.

Chunking is one of those hidden features of Clojure that you usually learn when it first bites you :)

Comment: whoa! [insert Conspiracy Keanu Reaves memehere]: I didn't see this coming! Thank you for the great answer!

Comment: No problem! I only saw this question because you posted it on #clojure on freenode.